# Notepad++ delete single instances of empty lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm familiar with how to delete blank / empty lines from a text file using Notepad++.

However, I can't see a way to delete single instances of blank lines (as in, rather than 1 single line on the whole text file, I'd like to be able to delete single empty lines, but not cases where there are e.g. 3 empty lines in a row).

Also, using the example below, is there any way to delete blocks of empty lines where there are more than 2 empty lines in a row, to be only left with 2 empty lines in a row. I realise I might need to run two different regex commands in a row rather than doing such a tidy up all at the same time.

For example, starting with this:

```
PROCEDURE post_insert (

  x_afe_number                IN VARCHAR2,

  x_afe_sub_type              IN VARCHAR2,

  x_amend_or_suppl_num        IN NUMBER);







PROCEDURE Insert_Row

    (x_rowid                       IN OUT VARCHAR2

    ,x_afe_number                         VARCHAR2

    ,x_afe_sub_type                       VARCHAR2

    ,x_amend_or_suppl_num          IN OUT NUMBER

    ,x_project_desc                       VARCHAR2
```

I'd like to delete the single empty lines, to end up with:

```
PROCEDURE post_insert (
  x_afe_number                IN VARCHAR2,
  x_afe_sub_type              IN VARCHAR2,
  x_amend_or_suppl_num        IN NUMBER);


PROCEDURE Insert_Row
    (x_rowid                       IN OUT VARCHAR2
    ,x_afe_number                         VARCHAR2
    ,x_afe_sub_type                       VARCHAR2
    ,x_amend_or_suppl_num          IN OUT NUMBER
    ,x_project_desc                       VARCHAR2
```

However, I can't work out how that can be done, since if I go to this:

```
Edit > Line Operations > Remove Empty Lines
```

I end up with this instead:

```
PROCEDURE post_insert (
  x_afe_number                IN VARCHAR2,
  x_afe_sub_type              IN VARCHAR2,
  x_amend_or_suppl_num        IN NUMBER);
PROCEDURE Insert_Row
    (x_rowid                       IN OUT VARCHAR2
    ,x_afe_number                         VARCHAR2
    ,x_afe_sub_type                       VARCHAR2
    ,x_amend_or_suppl_num          IN OUT NUMBER
    ,x_project_desc                       VARCHAR2
```

Comment: Try `(?s)(^(?<!.)|\S\h*\R)\R(?=\h*\S|\z)` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Would `\n\r\n` work for you, replaced by nothing?

Answer (score 0):

If you had 7 empty lines and you wanted to remove 4 of them,
then try this regex,
Find what: `^\n{4}`
Replace with: `nothing`

depends on your desired numbers to put them in between of  `{}`

Answer (score 0):

A method with Notepad++ is to use the find string `([^\r\n]\R)\R([^\r\n])` and replace with `\1\2`. This looks for a non-end-of-line character, followed by two end-of-lines, and then another non-end-of-line character. Two end-of-lines match the end of a non-empty line then an empty line. The replacement inserts the two saved non-end-of-line characters with one end-of-line between them. Select "Wrap around" and "Regular expression", then do a "Replace all". It may be necessary to do a second "Replace all", it is not needed for the example in the question, but would be needed to properly handle blank lines either side of a line containing just one character.

Explanation:

```
(                  Start of group
   [^\r\n]         One character that is not CR or LF
   \R              An end of line
)                  End of group
\R                 The unwanted empty line
([^\r\n])          Another group containing one character that is not CR or LF
```

Note that lines containing only spaces and/or tabs may not be treated correctly, the question is not clear on how they should be handled. If lines containing spaces and tabs should be considered as empty lines then first do a menu => **Edit** => **Blank Operations** => **Trim trailing spaces**, or alternatively do a regular expression replace-all of `^\h+$` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\r\n]\R\K\R(?=[^\r\n])|((\R)\2)\1*`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\r\n]         # not a linebreak
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(?=[^\r\n])     # positive lookahead, make sure we have a character that is not a linebreak after
  |               # OR
(               # group 1
    (\R)            # group 2, any kind of linebreak
    \2              # backreference to group 2, linebreak
)               # end group 1
\1*             # backreference to group , double linebreak, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, 2 linebreak
$2          # content of group 2, 1 linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vfUh8Q/1)

Answer (score -1):

After adrianHHH's answer I got attentive to your output sample text,  and noticed that you want to remove single empty lines too, so I prepared my second answer, which is   what you was waiting for .....
Find what: `^\n(?!\n{5})`
Replace with: `nothing`

[image]

After replace all

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how this works, or how it is intended to work. When I tried it, it removed **all** of the blank lines in the test file (Notepad++ 7.9.1).

Comment: Not all blank lines, the `^\n` will remove all blank lines one by one,  so we use here a negation of lookahead for a block of blank lines and we specify it with 5, to tell only block of five lines out of 7 .....I bet you understand better than me, this is why I'm unable to express my regex literally,  I updated my answer with a picture which I have tried to explain my regex, ,,,,  Note I'm using an editor called (NMM editor) from my android phone..

Comment: My earlier comment was wrong, my apologies, I had copied the regex wrongly. However, having corrected my regex I find it deletes many wanted lines. Please try the following: Position the curson on line 11 of the file (i.e., one of the lines marked with the red box), then search for the regex and do one replace. That will remove line 11. Do another replace and line 12 is removed. And so on. Finally, the question is about Notepad++ so the relenavce of NMM is not clear and, anyway, what is NMM? It is not listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors .

Comment: Yes,  it will be active untill it finishes all new lines if you keep on pushing replace one by one, I put my cursor on the first line,  and pushed replace as you said, it removed first blankline the  second then fourth, and immediately it jumped to line 7 and bypassed two blanklines, after removed all blanklines,  if you still keep pushing it, it will return back to bypassed lines and will do it job till nothing left....funny was

Answer (score -1):

To achieve your goal you should follow these three steps:

1. Like [AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) mentioned you should ensure that all you empty lines are realy empty.

> Note that lines containing only spaces and/or tabs may not be treated correctly, the question is not clear on how they should be handled. If lines containing spaces and tabs should be considered as empty lines then first do a menu => Edit => Blank Operations => Trim trailing spaces, or alternatively do a regular expression replace-all of ^\h+$ with nothing.

2. Get rid of all single empty lines by using the Find/Replace dialog (Ctrl + H).
   Insert this regex `(^\r\n)(?!\1)` into the "Find what" field and replace it with nothing.
3. Remove all occurences of more than 2 consecutive empty lines by using this regex `(^\r\n)\1+` in the "Find what" field and replace it with `\1\1` (two times pasting group 1 aka. empty lines).

Both RegEx in detail explained:

1. `(^\r\n)(?!\1)` matches an empty line not followed by another empty line:

```
(       start of first group
^       search from start of line
\r\n    followed by end of line character
)       end of first group
        (first group simply matches an empty line)
(       start of second group
?!      negative lookahead (match everything exept of...)
\1      reference of group 1 (empty line)
)       end of group 2
```

2. `(^\r\n)\1+` matches two or more consecutive emtpy lines:

```
(       start of group      
^       search from start of line
\r\n    followed by end of line character
)       close group
        (first empty line is found and can be referenced by group 1)
\1      extend the pattern by pasting group 1 behind the regex to repeat the "empty line"
+       add the "+" in order to match also more than two consecutive empty lines
```

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail. Step 2 appears to remove all of the blank lines, then there will not be any blank lines for step 3 to find. The question wants multiple consecutive blank lines to be left alone, only isolated blank lines should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianHHH for so politely pointing out my mistake! Have now corrected the post.